En una consulta en SQL Server y uniendo 4 tablas mediante CTE's, el GROUP BY agrupa por código, pero no por fecha
El problema con mi consulta radica en que los resultados que me da mi tabla de resultados no me dan mis registros agrupados por fecha, pero sí me los da agrupados por Código. ¿A qué se debe lo de la agrupación?
En general mis registros yo los quería agrupados por código de producto (CODIGO_PRODUCTO) y por fecha (FECHA)
;WITH 

CTERecepciones AS (

    SELECT  

         CODIGO_PRODUCTO,
         FECHA,
         0 AS PRODUCCION,
         SUM(CANTIDAD) AS RECEPCIONES,
         0 AS TRASLADOS,
         NULL AS FACTURA,
         NULL AS PRIORIDAD

    FROM ORACLE_INFO.dbo.tbl_TRANSACCIONES_INVENTARIO

    WHERE TRANSACTION_TYPE IN ('Intransit Receipt')
      AND SUCURSAL_DESC IN ('BR_CEDIS MONTERREY')
      AND LEFT(ORIGEN, 3) = 'B10'

    GROUP BY CODIGO_PRODUCTO, FECHA
),

CTETraslados AS (

    SELECT  

         CODIGO_PRODUCTO,
         FECHA,
         0 AS PRODUCCION,
         0 AS RECEPCIONES,
         SUM(CANTIDAD) AS TRASLADOS,
         NULL AS FACTURA,
         3 AS PRIORIDAD

    FROM ORACLE_INFO.dbo.tbl_TRANSACCIONES_INVENTARIO
    WHERE TRANSACTION_TYPE IN ('WIP Assy Completion')

    GROUP BY CODIGO_PRODUCTO, FECHA

),

CTEFacturas AS (

    SELECT 

         PRODUCTO,
         FECHA,
         0 AS PRODUCCION,
         0 AS RECEPCIONES,
         0 AS TRASLADOS,
         MAX(FACTURA) AS FACTURA,
         3 AS PRIORIDAD

    FROM ORACLE_INFO.dbo.tbl_VENTA_CIERRE_DIARIA

    GROUP BY PRODUCTO, FECHA
),

CTEPrioridad AS (

    SELECT 

         PRODUCTO AS CODIGO_PRODUCTO,
         FECHA_REPORTE AS FECHA,
         SUM(sg.PRODUCCION) as PRODUCCION,
         0 AS RECEPCIONES,
         0 AS TRASLADOS,
         NULL AS FACTURA,
         MIN(PRIORIDAD) AS PRIORIDAD

    FROM ORACLE_INFO.dbo.tbl_SUG_PRODUCCION sg

    GROUP BY PRODUCTO, FECHA_REPORTE

),

CTEUnion AS (

    SELECT * FROM CTERecepciones
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT * FROM CTETraslados
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT * FROM CTEFacturas
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT * FROM CTEPrioridad

)

SELECT  

     CODIGO_PRODUCTO,
     FECHA,
     SUM(PRODUCCION) AS PRODUCCION,
     SUM(RECEPCIONES) AS RECEPCIONES,
     SUM(TRASLADOS) AS TRASLADOS,
     MAX(FACTURA) AS FACTURA,
     MIN(PRIORIDAD) AS PRIORIDAD

FROM CTEUnion

WHERE YEAR(FECHA) = 2024 
  AND CODIGO_PRODUCTO LIKE '%Q%'  -- Filtro para registros con la letra "Q"
  AND PRODUCCION IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY CODIGO_PRODUCTO, FECHA

ORDER BY FECHA DESC


El título dice SQL Server, las etiquetas MySQL, y la consulta parece ser de Oracle. ¿Con qué base de datos estás trabajando?

¿Cuál es el resultado esperado, y cuál el obtenido? Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta.

el resultado esperado es que la consulta me agrupe por Código de producto y por fecha también, ahi lo puse arriba de la consulta. El obtenido (también lo puse en la consulta) es que me está dando solamente los registros de la columna codigo de producto agrupados y no me agrupa los de la columna fecha

Eso es lo que dijiste en tu pregunta. Presenta, con datos de muestra, tanto el resultado esperado como el obtenido. Y de nuevo: ¿con qué base de datos estás trabajando?

No estoy seguro si entiendo lo que dices. Tu consulta agrupa los datos por código de producto y fecha. Entonces te da un resultado con una fila por código de producto y fecha. Pero dices que tu resultado solamente está agrupado por código de producto. En otras palabras: recibes un resultado con una sola fila por código de producto. Dado que ordenas el resultado por fecha, quizás simplemente tienes que ver más bajo (deslizar verticalmente), para ver las otras filas de los productos. O quizás es que solamente hay datos por una fecha por producto en tus tablas.

No hay manera que esa consulta no agrupe por  código de producto y fecha. Quizás no comprendes lo que la agrupación hace, pero el código es claro y el resultado va a estar agrupado por código de producto y fecha, y ordenado por fecha. Es decir, vas a ver primero todos los productos de la fecha más reciente (sin un orden particular), luego todos los productos de la fecha inmediata anterior, y así sucesivamente hasta llegar al primer registro del 2024.

Me parece que el problema es porque tienes fechas con tipo de dato datetime que incluyen también la porción de la hora y por ello "no agrupa" por fecha.
Lo que tendrías que hacer es convertir la columna en date para que se pueda agrupar correctamente.
Dejo un ejemplo quitando la paja de la consulta.
SELECT  
     CODIGO_PRODUCTO,
     CAST(FECHA AS date) AS FECHA,
     SUM(PRODUCCION) AS PRODUCCION,
     SUM(RECEPCIONES) AS RECEPCIONES,
     SUM(TRASLADOS) AS TRASLADOS,
     MAX(FACTURA) AS FACTURA,
     MIN(PRIORIDAD) AS PRIORIDAD
FROM CTEUnion
WHERE YEAR(FECHA) = 2024 
  AND CODIGO_PRODUCTO LIKE '%Q%'  -- Filtro para registros con la letra "Q"
  AND PRODUCCION IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY CODIGO_PRODUCTO, CAST(FECHA AS date)
ORDER BY FECHA DESC;


Buen catch, la verdad es que sin ver datos de ejemplo, es fácil pasar por alto esos detalles.

Tal vez no sea la solución, pero es un error común en principiantes.
